# Mod Rewrite Map file not returning correct results

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Im using the following code in the mod rewrite.  I have a search parameter variable that I set before and use in the rewrite condition against a map file.  The Condition requires the map file to return a result but then I use the same mapfile in the rewrite rule and it returns and empty string.

```
 RewriteCond  ${root301:%{ENV:SEARCHURL2}|NOT-FOUND} !(^$|NOT-FOUND) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Page1?search2=${root301:%{ENV:SEARCHURL2}} [QSA,NE,R=301,L]
```

so for example http://mysite/root1 is suppose to go to http://mysite/page1?search2=results  but it ends up just going to http://mysite/page1?search2= with no search parameters.   if the map condition wasn't satisfied the rewrite wouldn't happen at all?  Im using compiled map files and I see the dictionary being compiled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue I had was that I actually had 2 similiar redirects one was looking for a url without the trailing forward slash but when I duplicated the first one I forgot to add the trailing forward slash to the redirect rule like below.  thus the search conditions weren't identical so of course it didn't work

RewriteCond  ${root301:%{ENV:SEARCHURL2}/|NOT-FOUND} !(^$|NOT-FOUND) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Page1?search2=${root301:%{ENV:SEARCHURL2}} [QSA,NE,R=301,L]